# Objective-C pattern for creating mutable copies

Tags: ios, objective-c, factory, nscopying, nsmutablecopying

I have many "model" objects whose properties are defined as "readonly" and shared among various components.

In some cases I need to create local mutable copies of the objects (using them for local mutable state)

I rather not implement NSMutableCopy protocol as the object should be immutable after it is created. The modified object could be "passed" around after copy+mutate operations.

Is there a suggested mechanism , or should I just implement a constructor receiving the "changed" parameters?

For example an object which parses a JSON to native types :

```
@interface ImmutableObject : NSObject
// various "readonly" properties
...
-(instancetype)initWithJSON:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) MyClass1 *prop1;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MyClass2 *prop2;
...
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray<MyClass100 *>  *prop100;

@end

@implementation 
-(instancetype)initWithJSON:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary {
  self = [super init];
  [self parseDictionaryToNative:jsonDictionary];
  return self;
}
@end
```

Somewhere in code:

```
ImmutableObject *mutated = [immutableObject mutableCopy]; // best way to accomplish this?
// change some values...
mutated.prop1 = ... // change the value to something new

self.state = [mutated copy]; // save the new object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@spinalwrap is correct, but in this case there is no reason to create the extra copy before storing it. `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`, so can be used anywhere an `NSArray` can be used (and this is very common). Same for yours. In your particular case, you'd probably do it this way:

```
MutableObject *mutated = [immutableObject mutableCopy]; // create an instance of MutableObject

mutated.prop1 = ... // change the value to something new

self.state = mutated; // Since `state` is an immutable type, 
                      // attempts to mutate this later will be compiler errors
```

This is safe because you know that this block of code is the only block that has a reference to the mutable version of the object (because you created it here).

That said, once you've created a mutable subclass, you now need to consider the possibility that any `ImmutableObject` you are passed might actually be a `MutableObject`, and so make defensive copies (just as is done with `NSArray`, `NSString`, etc.) For example:

```
- (void)cacheObject:(ImmutableObject *)object {
    // Need to copy here because object might really be a MutableObject
    [self.cache addObject:[object copy]];
}
```

This is made fairly efficient by implementing `copy` on `ImmutableObject` and `return self`, and implementing `copy` on `MutableObject` as an actual copy, usually like this:

*ImmutableObject.m*

```
- (ImmutableObject *)copy {
    return self;
}
```

*MutableObject.m*

```
// as in spinalwrap's example
- (MutableObject *)mutableCopy {
    MutableObject *instance = [MutableObject new];
    instance.prop1 = [self.prop1 copy]; // depends what you want here and what kind of class the properties are... do you need a deep copy? that might be a bit more work.
    // etc...
    return instance;
}

// No need to duplicate code here. Just declare it immutable; 
// no one else has a pointer to it
- (ImmutableObject *)copy {
    return (ImmutableObject *)[self mutableCopy];
}
```

So the copy is almost free if the object was immutable already. I say "fairly efficient" because it still causes some unnecessary copies of mutable objects that are never mutated. Swift's copy-on-write system for value types was specifically created to deal with this problem in ObjC. But the above is the common pattern in ObjC.

Comment: Since the class represents a fairly large model , creating 2 seperate classes is very tedious and error prone.

I was hoping there was a "swift" like mechanism to define a "var" rather than a "let" variable and automagically get a mutable version.

I've resorted to creating a copy of the original (returning an actual copy from the original , rather than "self") and using KVC to change the "readonly" properties, (since I am changing ~2-3 props).

Answer (score 1):

note that `NSMutableArray`, `NSMutableData` etc. are different classes than their immutable counterparts. So in this case, you maybe should define a `MutableObject` class with the same interface as the `ImmutableObject` class (but with mutable properties) and use that if you want to have a mutable object.

```
MutableObject *mutated = [immutableObject mutableCopy]; // create an instance of MutableObject

mutated.prop1 = ... // change the value to something new

self.state = [mutated copy]; // creates an ImmutableObject
```

the implementation of `ImmutableObject's` `mutableCopy` could be something like:

```
- (MutableObject *) mutableCopy
{
    MutableObject *instance = [MutableObject new];
    instance.prop1 = [self.prop1 copy]; // depends what you want here and what kind of class the properties are... do you need a deep copy? that might be a bit more work.
    // etc...
    return instance;
}
```

and `MutableObject's` `copy` method could look like this:

```
- (ImmutableObject *) copy
{
    ImmutableObject *instance = [ImmutableObject new];
    instance.prop1 = [self.prop1 copy];
    // etc...
    return instance;
}
```

You're not forced to use the `NSMutableCopy` protocol formally, but you can.